# Building Emailing Backend with Node js

Tags: node.js

I need to build an email backend that can receive email, send email, store them in the db, like other all email services, such as Gmail or Yahoo.

Which module should I use to build such app? I searched about this, but it's all about `nodemailer`, which is just a sending module.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you actually want with the backend.

For parsing mail messages i should use a package like `mailparser`. It tries to parse the source in different objects. Like to, cc, bcc, attachments, body etc.

For loading the messages, you can use one of the several IMAP clients. Store them with the mysql package.

Sending ofcourse with `nodemailer`.

The big question stays, what is the purpose of the backend. Creating a mail backend is not a easy task. Loading from IMAP and sending by SMTP is not the problem. But if you want create a service like Gmail or Yahoo, you need think about a lot aspects, like SPAM protection, queueing of mail, throttling of the outgoing mail and a lot more.